# How do we describe the region of integration of the proposed triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

When finding the volume outside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=25$ and inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=100$, the bounds are: $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $5 \leq r \leq 10$

What are the bounds for $z$?

Comment: Hint : $x^2+y^2\ge 25$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 100$. What follows from this for $z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

What is the intersection of the cylinder $x^{2} + y^{2} = 25$ and the sphere $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 100$?

Comment: z= 5sqrt(3) and z=-5sqrt(3)?

Comment: @Arnold that's the idea. Precisely speaking, $z$ ranges from $-5\sqrt{3}$ to $5\sqrt{3}$.